# returning the union of the types from arrays

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like this merge method to have a return type of a union of all the different array types passed into it.

```
type AnyIterable<T> = Iterable<T> | AsyncIterable<T>

async function* merge<T>(...iterables: Array<AnyIterable<T>>) {
  for (const iterable of iterables) {
    yield* iterable
  }
}

merge([1, 2, 3], ['1', '2', '3'])
// Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyIterable<number>'.
// Property '[Symbol.asyncIterator]' is missing in type 'string[]' but required in type 'AsyncIterable<number>'.ts(2345)
```

But I get that error. Obviously that's expected but I don't know how to type this to get the values from the array of iterables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I think people usually [want errors like this to happen](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15659), since heterogeneous arrays are less common than homogeneous arrays, and type inference that always widened until it worked would not catch actual errors.

If you want to work around this, it's possible the go the other direction: force the type inference to succeed, and then [calculate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) the value of `T` from it if you need it:

```
async function merge<I extends Array<AnyIterable<any>>>(...iterables: I) {
  for (const iterable of iterables) {
  }
}

type UnArrayAnyIterable<A extends Array<AnyIterable<any>>> = 
  A extends Array<AnyIterable<infer T>> ? T : never;
```

Now this succeeds:

```
merge([1, 2, 3], ['1', '2', '3']); // I inferred as the tuple `[number[], string[]]`
```

And if you want `T` you can use `UnArrayAnyIterable`:

```
declare function foo<I extends Array<AnyIterable<any>>>(...iterables: I): UnArrayAnyIterable<I>;
const ret = foo([1, 2, 3], ['1', '2', '3']); // string | number
```

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: You're fantastic at this. I appreciate all your help. Why does the UnArrayAnyIterable need to have a `?` in it? I don't really understand the syntax.

Comment: It's a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types).